# How to call in instance of Resource in Django Tastypie.?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Here is my tastypie code snippet.

I have a Resource and in `post_list` method , an instance of `Mysample` is getting created there.

I want to call a method of `Mysample` Instance , Please help me how to do that,

please find the comment in code where I need to call the method of `Mysample` instance

```
class MysampleResource(ModelResource):
    intfeild1 = fields.IntegerField('intfeild1_id', null=True)
    intfeild2 = fields.IntegerField('intfeild1_id')

    class Meta:
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = Mysample.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','delete',]
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = MysampleAuthorization()


    def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):

            result = super(MysampleResource, self).post_list(request, **kwargs)

            #here I want to call a method of Mysample Instance.
            return result
```

Please help me , I'm begginer, so could you please give suggestion on which method to override and where should I need to do that.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please add the error if you are getting any.It should work the you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add your method in your resource:

```
def test_method(self,param*):
        #Do your stuff
        return result
```

and within post_list you can call it like:

```
self.test_method(param*)
```

Note: The method declaration include 2 params but in python "self" is passed on as an implicit param so that when you call your method you don't pass on the self object.

- = could be more than just one parameter in that case use "," in order to separate them.

If we apply all the previous concepts your code should look like:

```
class MysampleResource(ModelResource):
    intfeild1 = fields.IntegerField('intfeild1_id', null=True)
    intfeild2 = fields.IntegerField('intfeild1_id')

    class Meta:
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = Mysample.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put','delete',]
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = MysampleAuthorization()


        def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):

                result = super(MysampleResource, self).post_list(request, **kwargs)

                #Let's say that you want to pass resquest as your param to your method
                method_result=self.test_method(request)
                return result

         def test_method(self,request):
                #Do your stuff
                return result
```